# How will I print datagridview contents on crystal report in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, connection

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load    
        Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM TBLName WHERE ID = " & Form1.Datagridview1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString() & ""
        Dim SqlCommand As New OleDbCommand
        Dim SqlAdepter As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim Table As New DataTable

        With SqlCommand
            .CommandText = SqlQuery
            .Connection = Form1.conn
        End With
        With SqlAdepter
            .SelectCommand = SqlCommand
            .Fill(Table)
        End With

        Dim crystal As New CrystalReport1

        crystal.SetDataSource(Table)
        rptviewer.ReportSource = crystal
        rptviewer.Refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm getting an error on this line

```
        .Connection = Form1.conn
```

what should I do??

Comment: what's the error you are receiving?

Comment: Error : conn is not a member of form1